# In Android Studio/IntelliJ, How to switch from Code Fragment mode to Expression mode?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm currently in Code fragment mode and don't see an option to switch to expression mode.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on arrows at the top right corner or press "Shift+Enter"